# Why -- ^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y) Pattern not found?

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 30 2017 18:21:38)
Included patches: 1-197, 322, 377-378, 550, 703, 706-707
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-R2d1UQ/vim-8.0.0197=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Set omnicompletion for php in my .vimrc file.

```
filetype plugin indent on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

To edit a test.php file,input the word `html` ,now i want to get all the php functions beginning with `html`.

`ctrl+x` result in  `-- ^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y) Pattern not found`.

Go on to press `ctrl+o` result in `Omni completion (^O^N^P) pattern not found`.

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are trying to use a completion function provided by a plugin. If that's right, you should ask your question on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/issues) the maintainer and/or the plugin's community will probably be able to help you.